# BitrixVM (на компе) вместо OpenServer + Git + BitrixVM(server)

Tags: битрикс, git, phpstorm, openserver

Уважаемые коллеги. 
Помогите разобраться. Суть такова.
Имеется сайт на сервере, сайт рабочий, чтобы не работать на рабочем сайте, настраиваю контроль версий Git. 
Для работы на локале используется OpenServer. Дело в том, что скорость сайта на OpenServere на низком уровне, т.к. не установлены необходимые акселераторы и тому подобное, страница грузится 20-30 сек.

Вот думаю, можно ли прикрутить виртуальную машину BitrixVM вместо OpenServer.

Вопрос в том, когда указывается путь к локальной версии сайта, то как указать в настройках git путь к проекту, тот, что на локале, чтобы я мог склонировать проект?

[image]

Может, есть другой вариант настройки.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > как указать в настройках git путь к проекту, тот, что на локале, чтобы я мог склонировать проект?

чтобы *склонировать* - пойдет любое указание

Comment: А зачем Вам вообще OpenServer, чем не устраивает [Веб-окружение от Битрикс](http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/env/)?

Comment: Я уже разобрался с данной сетью, кому интересно могу рассказать.

Comment: @murad30, лучше не «рассказать», а написать ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что автор «разобрался с данной сетью», а подробностей (вероятно, какая-то ошибка в настройке) не поделился, соответственно, вопрос бесполезен для сообщества.